# proliant dl 380 g4 outside deploy

Tags: hardware

I bought a dl380 server and the noise is very high to stay inside my home. Can i deploy the server outside (not in balcony, outside) in a box of metal? I need a specialist opinion because i can lose money, warranty and my server; this is the only solution available for me so has anybody tried something like this?

Comment: I've submitted an answer but you should bear in mind that you probably won't get your target audience for this question. If you're unhappy with my suggestion, a sister site like ServerFault.com might be a better bet and I can migrate your question for you (just flag the question and let us know).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could but:

- For your warranty you'd have to adhere to the manufacturer's operating specifications (temperature, humidity, etc) and then you'd have to provide something that met or exceeded that specification in all conditions. To meet temperature and humidity levels we're talking about air-conditioning and that's going to complicate the weatherproofing on the enclosure (IP66 is usually storm-sealed so you might need conductive cooling).
- You may also have building regulations to adhere to governing how something is installed externally (building, power regs, conservation areas) and who can install it.
- Your insurers may also take issue with a valuable system essentially being run outdoors but they should be fine as long as everything else is done professionally.

That considered, I think you would have to spend a ridiculous amount of money on this project. Outdoor, weather/climate-proofed racks are extremely *specialist* equipment.

Buy an indoor cabinet and some sound-absorbing foam. Bolt it to the most solid thing in the building. Then forget about it with the saving you could probably afford to take a few holidays.